# Structures and Free function to clear memory: C Programming

Tags: c, struct, structure, free

I am creating a program that will store traits of a person and their grades/GPA into a struct, then reprint out all those traits. The grades/GPA inputted are pointers of float type. I am having trouble with my free_mem function that will free the memory space. Student_t is the name of my struct data type and *stu is a pointer to the first student in an array of student records, and int students is an input values of the total number of students. My error message reads:

```
error: request for member 'list_grades' in something not a structure or union
error: request for member 'list_grades' in something not a structure or union
error: request for member 'grades_list' in something not a structure or union
error: request for member 'grades_list' in something not a structure or union
```

My function for the struct is...

```
typedef struct{
  int sid;
  char last_name[NAME_SIZE];
  char first_name[NAME_SIZE];
  float *list_grades;
  float gpa;
} student_t;
```

My function for freeing the memory is...

```
void free_mem(student_t *stu, int students){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<students;i++){
      free(stu.list_grades);
      stu.list_grades=NULL;  }
  free(stu.grades_list);
  stu.grades_list=NULL;  
}
```

EDIT: Manipulated my free function from stu.list_grades to stu->list_grades and grades_list to gpa, but still confused on the second part.

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'free' note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'float'
error: incompatible types when assigning the type 'float' from type void

My function for freeing the memory is...

```
void free_mem(student_t *stu, int students){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<students;i++){
      free(stu->list_grades);
      stu->list_grades=NULL;  }
  free(stu->gpa);
  stu->gpa=NULL;  
}
```

Comment: `stu.list_grades` --> `stu->list_grades`

Comment: You're using a structure pointer, not a structure, so you need to dereference it.  You can use `(*stu).list_grades`, but this syntax is a bit cumbersome, so C provides an equivalent shorthand, which is `stu->list_grades`.

Comment: This makes no sense:  `free(stu->gpa)`.  You're passing a `float` to `free`.  It's no different from `free(123.456)`.  Meaningless, right?  You need to pass a *pointer* to `free`, one which was returned by `malloc` or `realloc` etc.  You can't selectively free a piece of it.  You either free the entire thing or nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring when you try to use `free()` inside of your for loop.

`free()` has to be used on a **pointer**, but in your for loop you're trying to use it on *specific members* from inside the structure (the `list_grades` member, specifically).

The solution is to call `free()` on each pointer (which, assuming you created the array as an array of structures, is each **index** of the array that you passed into the function), perhaps like so:

```
void free_mem(student_t *stu[], int students){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        free(stu[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't shown the part where you initialize `student_t`.
Remember you only want to use `free()` a pointer, when you have dynamically allocated it, which means you used `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` on the pointer. Otherwise, you shouldn't free it.

```
void free_mem(student_t *stu, int students)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<students;i++)
  {
      free(stu.list_grades);
      stu->list_grades = NULL;  //stu is a pointer, so you need `->`

      // You said stu was a pointer to the first student. 
      // You want to iterate over them, so you want to point to 
      // the next element of the array containing all the students
      stu++;
  }

  // gpa is not a pointer, so you don't want to free it!
  // You only want to free pointer, which have been allocated using `malloc()`
  // free(stu->gpa);
  // stu->gpa = NULL;  
}
```